# Append session variable to string to create table name for mySQL query

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, session

sorry but i couldn't really think of a good name for this but. my problem is i have a website were you click a button it sent it to the database and then adds up all of the numbers there. i have that part done but. please don't ask questions about this but the user  to do this has to create a table specifically for his count. doesn't matter about that my problem is a session is made earlier of that persons place id so say he is 88. i have this at the moment to find that table and add up all the numbers

```
 session_start();
$id=$_SESSION['id'];

    include('db.php');


  $add=mysql_query('SELECT SUM(p1),SUM(p2) from `game88`');
  while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($add))
  {
    $mark=$row1['SUM(p1)'];
    $mark1=$row1['SUM(p2)']; 
    }
 ?>
```

but were it says from and game88

```
('SELECT SUM(p1),SUM(p2) from `game88`')
```

i need to find the the table based on the users session so i have tried this

```
'SELECT SUM(p1),SUM(p2) from `game" . $id . "`'
```

but it doesn't work. game is always the first bit of the table name and 88 is the users place which is created before. i need it to find that table game88 or whatever the users session is say 99 it would be table game99. i hope this is understandable. and please don't ask what this is for since it is to hard to explain. thanks for your help

Comment: This really seems like an [X Y Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) I suspect that you say *i have that part done but. please don't ask questions about this but....* because intuitively you already know that that logic is really the issue that you need to address

Comment: the problem is it is not coming up with the scores from the `game" . $id . "` but it is from wen i type in game88 which means that code doesn't work and i need help @DelightedD0D

Comment: But why do you create a new `table` for every game? It would be more appropriate to have a single `table` named `games` and have each user-game stored as a `row` with a `column` named `gameId` where you would store the value `88` or `89`  etc..... then just retrieve the row for the current gameId

Comment: this is why no questions but ill explain. ok . person clicks into page. types in game name and description.  takes you to next page gives you a id and saves that id. creates a table in database called game$id. $id being the users id.  sends to scoring page. you can add scores for 2 teams determine on you session.  and heres my issue. scores are added up. but i need it from the table game$id but it is not showing me the score total which works. since i tested it manually. i need it to show me the score. @DelightedD0D does this help a bit

Comment: We get it. What we're saying is that there's no need for a table. You can do all of that with a row or with several rows, one for each team playing in that game and add a `column`  called `teamId` if needed. See what we mean?

Comment: i can't change the score though for when they score but with my may i just add a 1 for the team who scores and add up everything. @DelightedD0D

Comment: Just add  another column to each team's row named `score`, when they score, get the row with that `gameId` and `teamId` and add 1 to the value in `score`. When you want to compare, get all rows with that `gameId` and iterate the results comparing or adding (or doing whatever with) the contents of `score`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem is not clear enough, but, what I undestard is: 
A loged user consults a table like:  TableName$userID to get his points, doesn't him?

So, first you must be sure the session have the actual id of the loged user, then consult on your php script if the table exists, if not, create it.
Then, make the Select Query like this:

`$tableName = game.'$id';
 $query = 'Select sum(p1), sum(p2) FROM $tableName';`

Hope I help you

Comment: thanks. the session does have data for the id. my problem is i need it to open the table game00. 00 being the session number. it needs to then add it up. this i already have done.

Comment: I think you should create just one table with the points and select the data sending the ID in Where clause...

Comment: Exactly :) @jack, what Jose said ^ these games should be rows, not tables

Comment: i can't because i don't know how to minus scores and change them to be plus 1 from the previous this is the simple way but its turing out difficult @DelightedD0D

Comment: just and UPDATE set p1 = p1 -1 Where id = $id  (for example)

Comment: using $tablename i can echo it fine it echo game$id $id being my id which is 80. it echo fine but when i put it into my $add=mysql_query('SELECT SUM(p1),SUM(p2) from $tableName'); it does not bring up the results @DelightedD0D

Comment: i got is @DelightedD0D

Comment: @jack IMHO you are going to look back on this at some point and wish you had switched to rows instead of tables. But Im glad you got it  sorted.

Answer (score 1):

by adding

```
$tableName = game.'$id';
```

and then adding it into my code like this

```
  $add=mysql_query('SELECT SUM(p1),SUM(p2) FROM '.$tableName.'');
```

i was able to bring up the results this is because i used

```
'.$tableName.'
```

Comment: Jack, the snippet feature when posting is for adding code that can be run in the browser, `html`, `css`, and `javascript`. For serverside code like this, instead, hightlight the code and click the brackets button shown here http://i.imgur.com/ScIegTX.png or just put 4 spaces in front of the code if its a single line l)